# How to add SSL to opensift

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openshift, redhat, private-key

Hello I finally got my ssl certificate from wosign (namely: 1_root_bundle.crt and 2_mydomain.com.crt)

I don't know how to add them to openshift. I went to the applications and edited mydomain.com 
There I upload in *SSL Certificate the second crt (file2_mydomain.com.crt), on Certificate Private Key* I upload my private key (I tried .ppk and .key) and on Private Key Pass Phrase I type the password used for the private key.

The probelm is that after saving these I get an error at the Certificate Private Key: "Invalid private key or pass phrase: Could not parse PKey: no start line."

I simply wasted 4 hours and don't know how to make it work and couldn't find anything on the internet about this error.

I also tried to upload the CSR file in the certificate private key field without success and I used the Apache cert files.

Please help

Comment: The support from openshift still doesn't answer. Please suggest something if you know.

Comment: since there are some significant changes between the versions, you may want to add some details about your openshift environment like the version for example.